# Firebase.onDisconnect() not working for me

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I"m using the firebase.onDisconnect() method to remove a users presence, but it's not firing after they logout/kill connection. In the componentDidMount, I call my listener, which writes the user's ID to the presence node. I have it setup that onDisconnect, it should remove the node. But it's not working.

After logging out/closing the window, in Firebase, the presence node remains with the userID showing true. It should have been removed.

I've reviewed others code, and it appears to be setup correctly...I can't see what I'm missing.

this is in state:

```
    state ={
         presenceRef: firebase.database().ref('presence')
    } 

     componentDidMount() {
        if(this.state.user) {
        this.addListeners(this.state.user.uid);
      }
    }
    addListeners  = currentUserUID => {
        if(snap.val() ===true) {
              const ref =  this.state.presenceRef.child(currentUserUID);
              ref.set(true);
              ref.onDisconnect().remove(err => {
                  if(err !== null) {
                      console.log(err);
                  }
              })
        }
      })
}
```

I logout, there is no error logged in console, however, the node is never removed from the presence

Comment: You indicate that you expect the `onDisconnect()` operation to execute after a "logout".  The event that triggers execution is the [server detecting no network connection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works).  Are you creating that condition?  Have you tried killing the app to see if `onDisconnect()` fires then?

Comment: I've totally killed/closed the browser....so that should be enough right?

Comment: Yes, that should be enough.  The disconnect may not happen immediately.  Try waiting a few minutes before checking to see if the data was removed.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't it. My browser has been closed all night and yet the node remains. Is there anything else that needs to be specified on onDisconnect() to have it remove the node?

Comment: have similar issue, `ref.onDisconnect().update(...)` trigger only after connection restored

Comment: Como foi mencionado pelo @ Bob Snyder, o fato é que devemos aguardar para que o onDisconnect() seja acionado. no meu caso leva em torno de 1 min.